# How can i check if the user is Logged In once?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

Hi im using Flutter and Redux for my app Project and i wanted to build a Tutorial Page (Intro page how to use the app), but this Tutorial Page should be shown only if its the first log in of the user, how can i do that or is there any article about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) to save the value, like initially for the fist time retrieve the `bool` value as `true` and when you have shown the tutorial page to the user, save this `bool` value to `false` in your `SharedPreferences`.

Next time the value retrieved will be `false` and you don't have to show tutorial. A glimpse of code will look like

```
if (shouldShow) {
   // show tutorial page and save the value to true in sharedPref.
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that SharedPreferenes returns a future. So you can just put a "async" keyword in your main function and load it there.